# Unable to start Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Can’t start Jenkins using [java -jar jenkins.war]

Thrown with below exception:

```
C:\Praveen Kumar Subramaniyan\07. Automation\99. Others>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Praveen Kumar Subramaniyan\07. Automation\99. Others\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jun 15, 2015 6:16:52 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jun 15, 2015 6:16:52 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.8
Jun 15, 2015 6:17:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\subramaniyanpk\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
?[33mJun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)

?[0m?[33mJun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@1b0fd6f: java.net.BindException:
 Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)

?[0mJun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: stopped w.{,file:/C:/Users/subramaniyanpk/.jenkins/war/},C:\Users\subramaniyanpk\.jenkins\war
Jun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
?[31mJun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        ... 7 more

?[0mJun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
?[31mJun 15, 2015 6:17:02 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:916)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:815)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225)
```

Understand that the port 8080 is used by some other service as below; however, not sure how to kill this and start Jenkins.

Can someone kindly help me on this, please.

```
C:\Praveen Kumar Subramaniyan\07. Automation\99. Others>netstat -ano | find "8080"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3532
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       3532
```

Answer (score 17):

1. Use the `--httpPort` command-line parameter to start Jenkins on a different port.
2. Add the `-p` switch to `netstat` to see IDs of the processes that the connections belong to. You may need to use `sudo` to see all processes.

Comment: Thank you Vadim, starting with different port using --httpPort works for me

Comment: Thank you Vadim, your comment was very helpful and i was able to start jenkins