# jenkins update error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, jenkins

I just got started with Jenkins, and I'm just trying to update.

FYI I have already read this: [Unable to start Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845945/unable-to-start-jenkins)

I also tried this: http://www.ramk.io/2014/06/updating-jenkins-ci-server-on-mac-os-x/

I am having issues even when Jenkins is the only thing running on port 8080.

The full error when I try to run:

```
java jar jenkins.war
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
Running from: /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 17, 2015 1:38:14 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Dec 17, 2015 1:38:14 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.9
Dec 17, 2015 1:38:15 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /Users/EightArmCode/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 17, 2015 1:38:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)

Dec 17, 2015 1:38:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2db7a79b: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)

Dec 17, 2015 1:38:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: stopped w.{,file:/Users/EightArmCode/.jenkins/war/},/Users/EightArmCode/.jenkins/war
Dec 17, 2015 1:38:16 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Dec 17, 2015 1:38:16 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:158)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    ... 7 more

Dec 17, 2015 1:38:17 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:924)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:816)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:83)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:79)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225)
```

As I mentioned, I have tried checking what else is running on 8080:

```
sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    810 jenkins  156u  IPv6 0x2e7be7a88f4bb833      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "and I'm just trying to update"?!

Comment: I am just trying to update jenkins.

Comment: Could you explain how to "^C that java -jar jenkins.war" ??

Comment: Check what Kenney said! you are already running it in a different process? You can check processes running using `ps -ef | grep jenkins`

Comment: That error means some process is already listening to the TCP port. Only one process can be listening to a given port at any time.

Comment: Have you tried stopping jenkins before running that jar? I think you are getting downvoted because `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` is a pretty self explanatory problem

Comment: Clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out how it works. You can kill jenkins, replace the jenkins.war file in the /Applications/Jenkins/ directory, and then restart it.

Answer (score 7):

Try to run jenkins with command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=XXXX
```

where XXXX is port different than default one 8080

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this problem by killing the running java process in the Activity Monitor. You can try the following:

1. Launch the Activity Monitor
2. Search for java
3. Select the running java process and click the (X) button at the top right corner of the window to kill it
4. Start the jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, every time I try to run the jar file. What I found is the jenkin is already running and so to solve it.

1. I stopped the running jenkins with `sudo service jenkins stop` first
2. Than only run the command `sudo java -jar jenkins.war`

Answer (score 0):

In my i fixed issue by editing service file **/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service**
in this file set port in below line

```
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=xxxx"
```

Also after updating the service need to reload the deamon

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then start the Jenkins service

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below command and was able to login into Jenkins.

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```